# Is there a one to one and onto relation between ISO-8601 UTC and Unix Timestamp?

Tags: time, unix-timestamp, iso8601

## Time Formats

A point in time is often represented as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), or as a human-readable [ISO 8601 date in UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) time string.

For example:

### Unix Time

Seconds since Epoch, or Unix timestamp, in seconds or milliseconds:

> 1529325705
>
> 1529325705000

### ISO 8601 Date

> 2018-06-18T15:41:45+00:00

## My question

Is there a one-to-one and onto relationship between the two? In other words, is there a point in time with a single representation in one format, and more than one, or zero, representations in the other?

Comment: Yes; for example, the unix timestamp `0`. It can be represented in ISO 8601, for example, as `1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00` or as `1970-01-01T01:00:00-01:00`. But maybe you're talking about ISO 8601 specifically in the UTC timezone (which the standard itself makes no guarantees about)?

Comment: Adding a clarification - I'm referring to UTC specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to find such a date. From the wiki article on Unix time:

> Every day is treated as if it contains exactly 86400 seconds,[2] so leap seconds are not applied to seconds since the Epoch.

That means that the leap seconds themselves cannot be represented in Unix time.

For example, the latest leap second occurred at the end of 2016, so `2016-12-31T23:59:60+00:00` is a valid ISO 8601 time stamp. However, the Unix time stamp for the second before, at 23:59:59, is represented as 1483228799 and the second after, 00:00:00 (on January 1 2017) is 1483228800, so there is no Unix timestamp that represents the leap second.

In practice, this is probably not a problem for you; there has only been 27 leap seconds since they were introduced in 1972.

---

<sup>It might be worthwhile to mention that most software implementations of ISO 8601 does not take leap seconds into account either, but will do something else if asked to parse `"2016-12-31T23:59:60+00:00"`. The `System.DateTime` class in .NET throws an exception, while it's also conceivable that a library would return 2017-01-01 00:00:00.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

No. there is a nice correspondence between the two, but the relationship is 1 to many, and strictly speaking there may not even exist a precise Unix millisecond for a given ISO date-time string. Some issues are:

1. There are some freedoms in the ISO 8601 format, so the same Unix millisecond may be written in several ways even when we require that the time be in UTC (the offset is zero).

   - Seconds and fraction of seconds are optional, and there may be a varying number of decimals on the seconds. So a milliseconds value of 1 529 381 160 000, for example, could be written as for example

     - 2018-06-19T04:06:00.000000000Z
     - 2018-06-19T04:06:00.00Z
     - 2018-06-19T04:06:00Z
     - 2018-06-19T04:06Z
   - The offset of 0 would normally be written as `Z`, but may also be written as you do in the question, `+00:00`. I think the forms `+00` and `+0000` are OK too (forms with a minus are not).
2. Since there may be more than three decimals on the seconds in ISO 8601, no exact Unix millisecond may match. So you will have to accept truncation (or rounding) to convert to Unix time. Of course the error will be still greater if you convert to Unix seconds rather than milliseconds.
3. As Thomas Lycken noted, leap seconds can be represented in ISO 8601, but not in Unix time.

Answer (score -1):

> In other words, is there a point in time with a single representation in one format, and more than one, or zero, representations in the other?

No. The UTC time depends on your geographic location, ie. your latitude and longitude. However, the UNIX timestamp is a way to track time as a running total of seconds. This count starts at the Unix Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC.
From [Unix TimeStamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/),

> It should also be pointed out that this point in time technically does not change no
>   matter where you are located on the globe.

Comment: This is actually incorrect; see my answer. However, it's only been incorrect for 27 seconds since 1972, so the statement has an "uptime" better than most cloud providers ;)

Comment: @TomasLycken Thanks. I never took leap seconds into consideration.

Comment: It is correct that ISO 8601 may also represent a time in some time zone using an offset from UTC, for example 2018-06-16T06:28:34.765+02:00. But the question explicitly asked about UTC time, and so the offset will always be zero.